# Getting React to appear after running webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

When I run `npm run webpack` everything loads without a problem except I'm unable to see the React code created. When going to `localhost:3000`, it says it doesn't exist and if I were to go to the html path, it still continues to not show jsx.

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "deploy": "webpack --mode production",
    "watch": "webpack --mode development --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "webpack": "4.35.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
module.exports = (env, options) => ({
    entry: {
        app: "./assets/js/app.jsx"
      },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

**babel.config.js**

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);

    const presets = [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      '@babel/preset-react',
    ]
    const plugins = [
    ]

    return {
      presets,
      plugins
    };
  }
```

**app.jsx**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = ({ title }) =>
  <div>{title}</div>

const title = "Hello World!"

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <App title={title} />,
        document.getElementById('root')
    )
});
```

Comment: So there's nothing in `dist/`? And why did you expect to be able to go to localhost, do you have a dev server configuration somewhere else?

Comment: @jonrsharpe the `dist` folder has the `bundle.js` file which gets created after webpack bundles. As for the dev server, I didn't configure anything for it. I haven't used webpack in a while and from what I last remembered, after setting React requirements and running webpack, it worked. We need to create a dev server in order to have React working? Final question is will this dev server also work for production in the future as well? Thank you for answering and helping.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "working". And no, that's why it's a *dev* server.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not having a dev environment solves the issue about why when going to `localhost:3000` it doesn't work. But, shouldn't React be showing when heading to the html file path? Since within the file we have a header tag as `<script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: It depends. Perhaps you don't have any local file server set up. Your browser won't necessarily be able to load the other files. Maybe check the Network tab to see what's happening to those requests.

Comment: I'm seeing an error within console saying `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.` I wonder if this is the cause of React not showing.

Comment: Seems pretty likely, I would think.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I found the solution for the relative path. Apologize if I wasted your time. The problem was I was calling my div with a class when I kept looking for `getElementById`. Thank you for the help. My last question is do you have any recommendation in regards to setting up a dev environment? Again thank you for the help.

Comment: That's too broad for SO. I'd recommend reading the webpack docs and looking at existing app templates.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That is true. Again thank you for the help and I'll look into what you've recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ---

```
const App = (props) => {
  <div>{props.title}</div>
}

const title = "hello World";

ReactDOM.render(<App title={title}/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting. This one didn't solve the problem I am currently having. I'm unable to see React components since it seems like the path isn't connected?

Comment: What change have you made, and why do you think it would solve the OP's problem?